# Why is the kernel of the Brauer homomorphism a module for the normaliser?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field. The Brauer morphism is defined as the map
$$M\mapsto Br_P(M):=\frac{M^P}{\sum_Q \text{tr}^P_Q(M^Q)},$$
where $Q<P$ where $M^P$ is the points in $M$ fixed by $P$, and $\text{tr}^P_Q:M^Q\rightarrow M^P,\ m\mapsto\sum_{g\in P/Q} gm$ is the relative trace map.

I am trying to show that the $\sum_Q \text{tr}^P_Q(M^Q)$ is a submodule for the normaliser $N_G(P).$ I've proved that

$$g\text{tr}^P_Q(a) = \text{tr}^{^gP}_{^gQ}(ga),$$
for $a \in M^P.$ For $g \in N_G(P),$ $^gP = P,$ so 
$$g\text{tr}^P_Q(a) = \text{tr}^{P}_{^gQ}(ga),$$
but I get stuck here. I tried to show that a transversal of $^gQ$ in $P$ is the conjugate of a transversal in $Q$ in $P$, but I couldn't do this, and I don't know how else to go forward.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're having a problem with. Isn't it obvious that a transversal of $^gQ$ in $^gP$ is the conjugate (by $g$) of a transversal of $Q$ in $P$?